# Eigenvalue decomposition of $D \, A \, D$ with $A$ symmetric and $D$ diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let $A$ be a real, symmetric matrix. It admits the eigenvalue decomposition

$A = U \Lambda U^T$

where the eigenvectors are chosen to be orthogonal. Let $D$ be a diagonal matrix and

$B = D A D = D U \Lambda U^T D = (DU) \Lambda (DU)^T = V \Lambda V^T. \tag{$\ast$}$

Assume none of $A$, $B$, and $D$ is the identity matrix, $I$. In general, we have that

$V^T = U^T D \neq V^{-1} = U^T D^{-1}$ and

$V V^T = D^2 \neq I$.

I would like to clarify my understanding of the situation. Are the following statements correct in general?

1. Eq. ($\ast$) is *not* an [eigenvalue decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix) of $B$.
2. Eq. ($\ast$) is *not* a [diagonalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) of $B$.
3. $A$ and $B$ have different sets of eigenvalues, and one can say nothing about the eigenvalues of $B$ based on the knowledge of $\Lambda$.

Thank you.

Regards,
Ivan

Comment: The inequalities below 'So, we have that' are clearly wrong, just let every matrix be the identity matrix and everything is equal. What exactly is an eigenvalue decomposition?

Comment: @GitGud, sorry, I don't get your point. I assume that none of the matrices is the identity matrix. I wrote "_an_ eigenvalue decomposition" as it is not unique.

Comment: I was just stating a trivial counter example to your statement. I'm pretty sure others can be found. Also nowhere in your question did you say the matrices weren't the identity matrix. As for the second part of my comment, I don't know what an eigenvalue decomposition is and I'm asking you to tell me, please.

Comment: @GitGud, that is why I used "in general." The definition of the eigenvalue decomposition can be found, e.g., [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix).

Comment: You only used 'in general' after the inequalities. As for the wikipedia link, it doesn't really help. I can't find the definition of eigendecomposition or eigenvalue decomposition. I can't help you. **Edit:** I can answer 2. and 3., though: it can surely be a diagonalization of $B$, just let everything be the identity matrix.

Comment: @GitGud, the eigenvalue decomposition of a matrix $A$ is a factorization of $A$ as $A = U \Lambda U^{-1}$ where $U$ is a matrix composed of the eigenvectors of $A$, and $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix composed of the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: @GitGud, I have added the "non-identity" assumption in the question.

Comment: I think you are right for all three points. We can only say something about the determinant of $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $U^T = U^{-1}$, so the congruence

$$A = U \Lambda U^T = U \Lambda U^{-1}$$

is also a similarity relation. In other words, the eigenvalue decomposition is a unitary **similarity** of $A$ and $\Lambda$.

Since the same cannot be said about $V := DU$, relation $(*)$ remains congruence that is not a similarity, hence it doesn't preserve the eigenvalues. However, it **is** a diagonalization *by congruence* (usually, when we say "diagonalization" without the additional "by *something*", we assume that it's "by similarity").

However, there is a relation between the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$, albeit a weaker one. By [Sylvester's law of inertia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), if $D$ is nonsingular, then $A$ and $B$ have the same number of negative, zero, and positive eigenvalues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding diagonalization, according to the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) given in Wikipedia, it should also be a similarity.

Comment: And thank you for the reference! I have not heard about this law.

Comment: You're welcome. As I have written in my answer: "diagonalization" implies "by similarity", but you can also make a "diagonalization by congruence". [Here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6530690) is just one random example of a research paper dealing with the subject.